# Jsoup just crawls limited number of links

Tags: jsoup

I am new to the jsoup and I need to use it but here is a problem. Just a limited number of links are crawled. I crawl http://shais.net/ and I just see 35 abs url whilst it has at least 430 links. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

        PreparedStatement statement = db.Connection.connection.prepareStatement("truncate record;");
        statement.execute();

        processPage("http://shais.net/");//TODO


    }

    public static void processPage(String URL) throws SQLException, IOException {

        String sql = "select * from Record where URL = '"+URL+"'";
        PreparedStatement select = db.Connection.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery();
        if(result.next()){

        }else{
            sql = "insert into record"+" (URL) values"+"('"+URL+"')";
            PreparedStatement statement = db.Connection.connection.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            statement.execute();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc =Jsoup.connect("http://shais.net/").header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")//TODO
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .timeout(600000).get(); 

            if(doc.text().contains("research")){

                System.out.println(URL);

            }


            Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link:questions){
            if(link.attr("href").contains("shais.net"))
                    processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
                    System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));

            }


        }

    }
```

Please help me that where is the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The site you try to load uses Javascript to build the DOM. JSoup dos not execute JavaScript, so you don't see the links.

You may use selenium webdriver together with HTMLUnit or phantomjs to access the page. Or you try to identify the AJAX calls that the site makes and call them with JSoup directly.

Another common cause of missing information in a JSoup document can be the size of the document. By default, Jsoup limits the size of each received document to 1M. If you want to get larger sites, you may need to raise that limit using `Jsoup.connect(URL).maxBodySize(0)`, but you do that already it seems.

Comment: Thank you. For this site https://globerunner.com/ also just indicates 26 links. And is there any other API or tool that I can use with Java? Thanks.

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi, you can check where the website JavaScript loads its data from, using your browsers developer tools, and then directly load it in your code.